# Algebraically independent sets and not inclusion argument

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, transcendental-numbers

Let $A$ and $B$ be nonempty sets and let $A\cup B$ be algebraically independent set over $\mathbb Q$ and $A\cap B=\emptyset$ . Let $C\subset\mathbb Q.$ Now, fix an $r\in R$ we have, $$ r\cdot A\cdot C\not\subset B$$ where $A\cdot C=\{a\cdot c\colon a\in A\ \&\ c\in C\}.$

It is enough to show that $r\cdot A\not\subset B.$
If $r\in\mathbb Q$ then it is an impossible because $A\cup B$ is algebraically independent. Otherwise, $r\in\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$, for contradiction, assume $r\cdot A \subset B.$. Then for every $x\in A$ there exists $y_x\in B$ such that $r=\frac{y_x}{x}$. Also, $r=\frac{y'_{x'}}{x'}$ where $x'\in  A$ and $y'_{x'}\in B$. But this means, $r\in\mathbb Q(x,y_x)\cap\mathbb Q(x',y'_{x'})=\mathbb Q.$
Here I used the well known result: Let $E$ be an extension field of the field $F$  and suppose that $a,b\in E$ are algebraically independent over
$F$. Show that $F(a)\cap F(b) = F.$
which is a contradiction since $r\not\in\mathbb Q$. In case $y_{x}=y'_{x'}$, it also gives a contradiction.

Now, I proved $r\cdot A\not\subset B$, which means, there exists at least $x^*\in A$ such that $r\cdot x^*\neq y$ for all $y\in B.$ To complete the proof, for contradiction, assume  $$ r\cdot A\cdot C\subset B$$

This means,  there exist $q,q'\in\mathbb Q$ and $y_q,y'_{q'}\in B$ such that
$r\cdot x^*\cdot q=y_q$ and $r\cdot x^*\cdot q'=y_{q'}$. But  this impossible because $$r\cdot x^*(q'y_q-q y_{q'})=0$$ since $rx^*\neq 0$ so $q'y_q-q y_{q'}=0$ which is contradiction since $\{y_q, y_{q'}\}$ is algebraically independent. This finihes the proof.

My question, Does the prove above correct? Is there is short way to prove that?

Any help will be appreciated greatly.

Comment: Take $A=\{\pi\}$, $B=\{\pi,e^\pi\}$, $C=\{1\}$ and $r=1$. Then $A\cup B$ is algebraically independent and $rAC=AC=A\subset B$.

Comment: Randy Marsh, I forgot, they must be disjoint. I fixed now. Is okay now ?

Comment: You also want $A$ and $B$ to be non-empty.

Comment: Randy , yes, I added. Does work now? what are comments about the proof. if there is another way to do it. without spilt to two cases.

Comment: You want both $A$ and $B$ to be nonempty, not just $A\cup B$ to be nonempty.  Otherwise, if $A=\emptyset$ and $B\neq\emptyset$, then $A\cap B=\emptyset$ and $rAC=\emptyset\subset B$.

Comment: Randy, Thank so much for reading carful my question. How was it now.  Do you have an easy way to show that?

Comment: Randy, I added more details